# Create dictionary with dynamic keys in C#

Tags: c#, function, dictionary, unity-game-engine

When programming with C/C++ I sometimes used to have a dictionary with references to functions according to the specified keys. However, I don't really know how to have something similar in C# allowing me **dynamic keys**.

I'm working on Unity and I'd like for exemple to invoke a function when I press left mouse click on my Unity project, is it possible ?

I'd really appreciate every comments on this.

Comment: Do you mean keyboard key's?

Comment: Did you try to use a dictionary like `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<KeyEnum, System.Func...>` already ?

Comment: Do you mean invoke a function based on the key that was called? I.E storing something like a delegate or Action?

Comment: I mean mouse key's like "GetMouseButtonDown(0)" or "GetMouseButtonUp(0)"

Comment: Yes that's it Plusheen, I'd like to invoke a function based on the key that was called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action>` signature to accomplish that. Get all the code codes and store them into an array with `System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode));`. You can then pair your keys with your functions with `keyCodeToFuncDic.Add(KeyCode.YourKeyCode, YourFunction);`

In the `Update` function, use for loop to loop over the `KeyCodes` stored in the beginning. Check if any of those keys is pressed. If pressed, check if it is in the `Dictionary`. If the that `KeyCode` exist in the dictionary, use the pressed key to `Invoke` the function in the `Dictionary` value, which will eventually call the function that is stored in the `Dictionary`.

Code:

```
Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action> keyCodeToFuncDic = new Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action>();
Array allKeyCodes;

void Start()
{
    //Get all codecodes
    allKeyCodes = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode));

    //Register Keycodes to functios
    keyCodeToFuncDic.Add(KeyCode.Mouse0, myFunction); //Left mouse
    keyCodeToFuncDic.Add(KeyCode.Mouse1, myFunction2); //Right mouse
}

void myFunction()
{
    Debug.Log("Left Mouse Clicked");
}

void myFunction2()
{
    Debug.Log("Right Mouse Clicked");
}

void Update()
{
    foreach (KeyCode tempKey in allKeyCodes)
    {
        //Check if any key is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(tempKey))
        {
            //Check if the key pressed exist in the dictionary key
            if (keyCodeToFuncDic.ContainsKey(tempKey))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Pressed" + tempKey);

                //Call the function stored in the Dictionary's value
                keyCodeToFuncDic[tempKey].Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use this:
First define a Delegate for your task (Jobs assigned to keys press in your example):

```
public delegate void MyJob();
```

Then define your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, MyJob> myBinding = new Dictionary<string, MyJob>()
{
    { "left", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Left Key pressed"); } },
    { "right", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Right Key pressed"); } },
    { "up", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Up Key pressed"); } },
    { "down", delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Down Key pressed"); } }
};
```

And finally use it:

```
public void Mapper(string pressedKey)
{
    myBinding[pressedKey]();
}
```

I hope this help you to solve your problem. If you need to more detail let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When I see "dynamic keys" I think for something else like having a `dynamic` type be the key for the dictionary. However what you need can be easily achieved. In C# "pointers to functions" are called `delegates` (but way better than C pointers to functions) thus you need a dictionary that has the `char` type as the key and one of those delegates as the value. In .net framework 4.0 and above there are predefined generic delegates called `Func<T...>` and `Action<T...>`. Basically if you want your function to return a value you will use `Func` and the `Action` will be used in the place of a `void` method.

So you can have something like this:

```
var keyMap = new Dictionary<char, Func<string, bool>>()
{
    {'w', MoveUp},
    {'s', MoveDown},
    {'a', s => true}, // using lambda expression
    {
        'd', delegate(string s)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) == false)
            {
                //
            }
            return true;
        }
    } // using anonymous method
};

// then you can call those like this
var allow = keyMap['w']("some input");
if (allow)
{
    // .... 
}

public bool MoveUp(string input)
{
    return true;
}

public bool MoveDown(string input)
{
    return true;
}
```

Here are the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx