# configurable hotkeys for button presses c#

Tags: c#

Im looking for a way that so Users that use my Program can change the Hotkeys theirself so its not bound to D,F12,K,F,A and so on.. i kinda want that ppl can change it via a Textbox or maybe via a Settings File. Been Stuck on it for couple Weeks now and i just cant find a way to make it happen, its my first Program im working on.

```css
    public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.D:
            // stuff
            Salvagebtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.F12:
            // stuff
            pausebtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.K:
            //stuff
            Geardropbtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.F:
            //stuff
            Gamblebtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.A:
            //stuff
            LeftClickSpambtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.H:
            // stuff
            openGRbtn.PerformClick();
            break;
        case Keys.B:
            //stuff                    
            gemupbtn.PerformClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace the literal `Keys` values with an array (or `Dictionary`) of `Keys` values indexed by an `enum` representing the command/purpose of each key e.g. `enum { PauseKey, GearDropKey, GambleKey }` and read in the collection from a file and add an editor for the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a few minutes, during commercials.  So, I wrote the following:

**EDIT : Code wrapped with a global keyboard handler.  You will also need to add a reference to PresentationCore and WindowsBase ...**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100,
                          WM_KEYUP = 0x0101,
                          S_WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0104,
                          S_WM_KEYUP = 0x0105;

        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private static Form1 hookForm;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        static bool bShortcutPressed;

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (hookForm.Handle != GetForegroundWindow())
            {
                if (nCode >= 0 && ((wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) || (wParam == (IntPtr)S_WM_KEYDOWN)))
                {
                    int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

                    bool bCtrl = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl));
                    bool bAlt = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt));
                    bool bShift = (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift));

                    Keys hookKey = (Keys)vkCode;

                    hookKey = (bCtrl) ? ((Keys.Control | hookKey)) : hookKey;
                    hookKey = (bAlt) ? ((Keys.Alt | hookKey)) : hookKey;
                    hookKey = (bShift) ? ((Keys.Shift | hookKey)) : hookKey;

                    Debug.Print($"hookKey {hookKey} {bCtrl} {bAlt} {bShift}");

                    if (!bShortcutPressed && dicTest.ContainsValue(hookKey))
                    {
                        hookForm.OnKeyDown(new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs(hookKey));
                        bShortcutPressed = true; Debug.Print($"{bShortcutPressed}");
                    }
                }

                if (nCode >= 0 && (((wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP) || (wParam == (IntPtr)S_WM_KEYUP)))) { bShortcutPressed = false; Debug.Print($"{bShortcutPressed}"); }
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        static Dictionary<string, Keys> dicTest = new Dictionary<string, Keys>();

        public void AddHotKey(Action function, Keys key, bool ctrl = false, bool shift = false, bool alt = false)
        {
            KeyDown += delegate (object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) { if (IsHotkey(e, key, ctrl, shift, alt)) { function(); } };
        }

        public bool IsHotkey(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs eventData, Keys key, bool ctrl = false, bool shift = false, bool alt = false) =>
                             eventData.KeyCode == key && eventData.Control == ctrl && eventData.Shift == shift && eventData.Alt == alt;

        public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

            hookForm = this;

            KeyPreview = true;

            String[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys));

            foreach (string key in names) { comboBox1.Items.Add(key); }

            comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items[0];

            KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print($"Form1_KeyDown : {e.KeyData}");
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) => UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Keys hookKey = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), comboBox1.Text);

            hookKey = (checkBox1.Checked) ? ((Keys.Control | hookKey)) : hookKey;
            hookKey = (checkBox2.Checked) ? ((Keys.Alt | hookKey)) : hookKey;
            hookKey = (checkBox3.Checked) ? ((Keys.Shift | hookKey)) : hookKey;

            if (!dicTest.ContainsValue(hookKey))
            {
                Debug.Print($"Going to add : {hookKey} : to our Shortcut Dictionary<>");

                dicTest.Add("test", hookKey);

                AddHotKey(() => { button2.PerformClick(); }, (Keys)new KeysConverter().ConvertFrom(comboBox1.Text), checkBox1.Checked, checkBox3.Checked, checkBox2.Checked);

                //checkBox1.Enabled = checkBox2.Enabled = checkBox3.Enabled = comboBox1.Enabled = button1.Enabled = false;

                label2.Text = "Go ahead and tryout your Shortcut now ...";
            }
            else { label2.Text = "Shortcut key is already stored in our Dictionary<> ..."; }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Debug.Print($"Button2 was clicked"); }
    }
}
```

**You're presented with:**

[image]

**Trying the desired shortcut out:**

[image]

Just an example, to show there are many ways to do things.

Easy to write them out to a file or something.  If you were going to ... I'd change the AddHotKey Action param to a string which contains a function name and then using different methods you can have it invoke that function.

Really though, I'd incorporate a Dictionary as the one talked about below.

Comment: Looks go so far i have 2 questions about it tho... 1st. instead of the Messagebox.show event i tried doing `Button2.Performclick` didnt worked that way. and 2nd i want these Hotkeys to work when the Program is in the background, i used a GlobalKeyboardhook for the Code i used first, but didnt got it to work with Hotkey thing. but otherwise it looks like thats the thing i want. Sry if any of the questions are dumb im still new to learning c# :D

Comment: You should be able to put any code in it.  It's just an Action being sent in as a lambda.  I added a button on the form and changed the lambda to: () => { button2.PerformClick(); }  If your Global Keyboard hook is working ... Your shortcuts should be executing.  Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: ok was just me beeing stupid :D only thing i need now is to save the Hotkeys after the Set Button gets pressed and Load it back when Program starts :D

Comment: and it seems like that my Keyboard hook is not working with that funtion will have to search for another Method :D But really thanks for your Help.

Comment: Oh ... Your hook is getting the key(s).  You have to add code in your Hook procedure to determine if it's a shortcut and then execute whatever.  I'll work on it later for you.

Comment: Shortcut keys work now, whether or not the app has focus.  **BUG: If you hold down the shortcut keys, it will fire over and over.**  As far as saving & loading shortcuts ... there should be many examples of that here and there.  If I can fix the prementioned BUG, I'll post the code.

Comment: Isn't that easy to fix with a Timer ? And I guess for Saving and Loading I can use the User Settings thing as usual and yeah my Keyboard Hook was wrong for that :D

Comment: Timer? No? It's just, holding down a key is getting fired over and over, which it's supposed to.  Since your shortcuts can be anything ... like just F1 ... that is a "problem".  Otherwise, I could probably add a hack, to fix it.  Still thinking about it.

Comment: Ok ... Added a Dictionary and ShorcutFired flag. So, I think, I fixed the continuous firing problem. I was still getting multiple firings when I had the MessageBox.Show() in there. I don't know if it was causing KeyUP events to fire or what. So, I switched it to a Debug.Print() and it seems to "work". Hopefully, there's enough there now, for you to get your stuff going.

Comment: You helped me so much also with the stuff :D I hope all others that need the feature will get helped by it aswell Thanks alot

Comment: actually wasnt really able to test the Background Thing after it didnt worked on my own Program i tried only copying the code still doesnt seem to work in the Background. Its for a game which is in Borderless Windowed Mode, as you can see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntGowy5D9AE otherwise all the other stuff is working or is me missing something important ? Reference is added aswell..

Comment: My code had test code in it.  When you set the shortcut in the app, you are adding it to the **Dictionary<>**?  Also, as mentioned the continuous firing "bug" is there is the app is popping up a MessageBox.  Don't know why.  Like I said, after switching it to a Debug.Print(), I saw it was working.  Thought it was.

Comment: ok got everything to work now with my own program the only thing i want to know if the  `dicTest.Add("test", (Keys.Control | Keys.U));` can be added with the `Button1_Click` and if so how can i make it that the `(Keys.Control | Keys.U)` can be the Value from the Combobox + Checkboxes ? otherwise i just go the noob version and add alot of `dicTest.Add` :D.

Comment: Many ways to store stuff, I'd use JSON .NET.  But, for you, I'd Youtube using appsettings in Visual Studio or even "better" let's go old school and just use an INI file.  Here's a video that shows you how.  I admit I only flipped thru it.  But, I believe he shows you everything.  There's a link in his description for the INI class you need to import "reference" in your project. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvfN8JTUPgc

Comment: yeah INI file works like a Charm the users that are using the Program are happy now :D Like i said cant say in words how thankful i am.

Comment: You got that implemented fast.  Great.  Glad you got everything you needed.

Comment: Update the Answer slightly.  I'm also going to keep working on this.  Discovered, the system is really picky about key combinations.  Especially, trying to use Shift & Alt.

Comment: Above works "better"  Just have to be careful, with Shift and Alt.  Things, like Shift + NumPad5 or Alt + NumPad5 don't work. They have to be Shift + Clear and Alt + Clear.  Cause, it takes Shift and Alt into consideration.  Makes sense.  So, a few combinations might be "trial and error" for users.

Comment: Yeah after testing the updated code it works better on my Test Code.  Before on my Beta Version you had to press Hotkeys like "Shift + D" twice to get the button activated.

Comment: I actually used the firing bug for a feature left click macro. :D Will look for another way to add the macro again after I'm back from vacation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a myriad of different ways you could handle this. Personally, I'd opt for using a `Dictionary` with the Keycode as the Key, and a delegate/action as the value. Then on the keypress, you just call the function in the dictionary that's associated with that keycode. Something along the lines of:

```
Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action> keyDict = new Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action>();

// populate it however you wish. Whether it's user entry or from a file or something.
keyDict.Add(KeyCode.D, SomeFunction);
```

If you want to change the delegate in the dictionary:

```
keyDict[KeyCode.D] = SomeOtherFunction;
```

Then later in the event handler:

```
public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyDict[e.KeyCode].Invoke();
}

public void SomeFunction()
{
    Console.WriteLine("called some function");
}
```

(This question might have a bit more detail if needed: [Create dictionary with dynamic keys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364770/create-dictionary-with-dynamic-keys-in-c-sharp))

Comment: I like what you did ... But, He wants the user to be able to define the key combinations themselves, either in a UI or stored in a file.  I mean, yes, you could add code on top of what you have to do this ...  It'd be a good starting point, for somebody like me.

Comment: This was more addressing the immediate issue in the question; making the key bindings dynamic and not hard-coded. Storing them in a file or manual user input is a whole 'nother monster.

Comment: Oh absolutely ... You are definitely correct.  & like I said, I like what you did.